# WebStorm-compatible referencing a config file in JSDoc

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, jsdoc

I have `foo/defaults.yaml` file in my project. Then there is `foo.js` that uses data from this file.

I would like to make a JSDoc comment the following way:

```js
/** Actually launches real Foo missiles. The default values are read from @link foo/defaults.yaml. */
async launchFooMissiles() {
   await openHatch()
   const defaults = await readTheDefaults('foo/defaults.yaml')
   ...
}
```

Is there a way to specify the reference so there is a clickable link in the tooltip? You can have symbols clickable, such as `@see missileHelper` and many other ways, but what about files?

Comment: 1) AFAIK for inline tahs you should really use them this way: `{@link foo/defaults.yaml}` (surrounded by `{}`). 2) What about `@see` tag -- any difference in behaviour? 3) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-51928

Comment: 4) What I may suggest right now: when you need to go to such a file, select the file reference (`foo/defaults.yaml` in this example) and invoke `Navigate | File...` shortcut (or Search Everywhere `Shift+Shift`). Not great, but should work in most cases IMO. See how it will do for you.